# Finite presentation of R-modules in an exact sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have trouble proving the following question.  Suppose we have an exact sequence $L\to M \to N \to 0$ of $R$-modules, with $M $ finitely presented and $L$ finitely generated. Show that $N$ is finitely presented.

Previous result: 
Suppose we have maps of $R$-modules $f:L\to M$ and $g:M\to N$. Then we can construct an exact sequence
$0 → ker(f) → ker(g ◦ f) → ker(g) → coker(f) → coker(g ◦ f) → coker(g) → 0.$

And the hint is to use this previous result on a map $R^n\to M\to N$, this can be constructed by using the finite generation of $L$. But then I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since M is finite presented,so we have the following commutative diagram and $Ker \epsilon$ is finite generated.
[image]
The morphism $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are induced.

By 5 lemma we can show that $\alpha$ is epimorphism.by snake lemma 
 we have $\beta $ is an isomorphism.

since L is finite generated,$Im f$ is finite generated.And we get $\alpha$ is epimorphism and $Ker \alpha$ is finite generated before.So $Ker g\epsilon$ is finite generated.

So N if finite presented.